# .htaccess redirect from subdomain's articles to main domain without subdomain url change

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain, www.example.com and subdomain  test.example.com.  When i call test.example.com i need to redirect this to  www.example.com/search/property/test_state  without changing the url from test.example.com. so the url should look like test.example.com only.

I did this with the .htaccess code like,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webmail\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule  ^$ /search/property/%1_state [P]
```

Now  after this when i access any urls from the subdomain  like test.example.com/content/sell_your_home it should not change the url to main domain. 
currently when i access this it is redirecting to main domain. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the test subdomain has the same server root (document root) as the main domain, then you don't need the `P` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webmail\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule  ^$ /search/property/%1_state/ [L]
```

Otherwise, you need the full URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webmail\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule  ^$ http://www.example.com/search/property/%1_state/$1 [L,P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webmail\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: Not working..here i need two redirects. One should redirect test.example.com to  http://www.example.com/search/property/test_state  and the second one is  test.example.com/any_urls.php to same http://www.example.com/any_urls.php  however the browser should show the subdomain url on both cases. Here in second case it is showing  the mail domain url.

Comment: @user2890708 in the first case (same document root), change is simple. In the case of different document root, need an extra proxy rule